# Cannot print current value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my code:

codepen.io/bedtvapp/pen/NMoBby

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <h1>AngularJS Directive Controllers</h1>
  <div ng-init="count1 = 1"></div>
  <div ng-repeat-start="a in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" ng-init="$parent.count1 = $parent.count1 + 1"></div>
  <div>
  abc {{ a }} - {{::$parent.count1}} </div>
  <div ng-if="$parent.count1 % 2 == 0">breakline</div>
  <div ng-repeat-end></div>
</div>
```

I want to count item in array into custom variable (count1) (not $index). Because I will add more condition to my counting later.

Comment: Not sure, what you're trying to do here. Also paste the code inside question here as well.

Comment: what did you expect to happen? `ng-init="$parent.count1 = $parent.count1 + 1"` overwrites `$parent.count1` **everywhere** when it renders it. Consider using `$index` inside `ng-repeat` block

Comment: I want to do custom counting inside ng-repeat

Comment: @complez use the second array with the same length and pull out the numbers from it: `{{ count_array[$index] }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print count then just do following changes in your code

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <h1>AngularJS Directive Controllers</h1>
    <div ng-repeat-start="a in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" ></div>
    <div>
        abc {{ a }} - {{$index + 1}} </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end></div>
</div>
```

You no need to do any initalization thing

Comment: I want to do custom counting inside ng-repeat. For experiment

Comment: Could you please let me know which type of counting you suppose to do so i can have idea and will guide you

Comment: You want total count of array in count1 or you want something else could you please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

If you increment count1 in ng-repeat-start init,  end of the repeat count1 have the same value. So you need to get the help of $index. You can use count1 for the set starting value.
You can simply achieve your target using bellow code

```
  <div ng-init="count1 = 1"></div>
  <div ng-repeat-start="a in [1,2,3,4,5]" >
       abc{{a}}- {{count1+$index+1}}
  </div>
  <div ng-if="(count1+$index+1) % 2 == 0">breakline</div>
  <div ng-repeat-end></div>
```

output like this,

```
abc1- 2
breakline
abc2- 3
abc3- 4
breakline
abc4- 5
abc5- 6
breakline
```

If you want to add more condition you need based on `(count1+$index+1)` value.